# Adding Custom Settings Tabs to Custom Module in Dotnetnuke (DNN)

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I'm writing a new module in DNN 6 (Same question for DNN 5). By default you have some default tabs for settings in module settings section of any module you put in a particular page. 
For example in the picture below, we've got "module settings", "permissions" and "page settings".

[image]

The question is that how can I add more tabs (more than one) in settings section of the module. For examlple one tab for "general settings" and another one for "advanced settings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add any code you need in ascx and add codes in code behinde in update and load methods. this code can help you: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Community-Exchange/view/question/id/240.aspx

Comment: dotnetnuke site have changed and links are gone!

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20130506070659/http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Community-Exchange/view/question/id/240.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you just need add some code in the settings.ascx control, it will auto add a new tab in the setting section.
if you want to set a special name for your settings, just modify the node of *.dnn file:

```
<moduleControl>
<controlKey>Settings</controlKey>
<controlSrc>DesktopModules/YourModuleName/Settings.ascx</controlSrc>
<supportsPartialRendering>False</supportsPartialRendering>
<controlTitle>xxSetting(any name you want) Settings</controlTitle>
<controlType>Edit</controlType> <iconFile />
<helpUrl />
<viewOrder>0</viewOrder>
</moduleControl>
```

Comment: What sort of code should I add to settings.ascx? How if I want to add more than one Tab? Should I have multiple settings.ascx files? I Know you can't comment because of your score. Please edit your answer or add another reponse. Thanks